# How to get Ribbon button name when Ribbon xml is used?

Tags: custom-controls, vsto

I am implementing the Addin using VSTO 2010.

The addin is implemented using Ribbon xml and now i want to get the ribbon name
in order to change its visibility and customize it accordingly. How can I make the visibility set for the Ribbon button? And also how can I enable / disable the button based on the cell selection?

I am using .net c# 4.0 VSTO 2010 for office 2010

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cant set visibility to Ribbon but you can control the visibility of tabs in your ribbon.

Ribbon.xml

```
<tab id="TabTest" label="Test" getVisible="TabTest_Visible">
```

Ribbon.cs

```
public bool TabTest_Visible(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
     return false;
}
```

Comment: @Kiru-Cant I even enable or disable the button from Ribbon xml? I want to return true of false based on the cell selection or when particular cell is selected? Not even the ribbon button?

Comment: You could do for buttons as well,they have getEnabled and getVisible call back events.

Comment: Edit your question or ask as different question about cell selection.